# Putting up jersey webservice + MySQL database live

Tags: java, android, hosting, jersey

Over the past two weeks i have been developing a jersey RESTful webservice and a MySql database that it communicates with. Now my Android application is done which gets it's resources from the webservice. During the whole development time i've had the webservice on a tomcat server on localhost. But now I need my service to go live.

And I dont even know where to start. How can I make it go live? What hosting companies are there that supports these demands and where do I start? How does the webservice -> database connection looks like on the hosting part? Is tomcat commonly used to host?

As you can see I got close to no knowledge about this and a wink in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a hosting service that supports Tomcat and MySql.

[This](http://www.tomcathostingservice.com/) what i found googling "tomcat hosting service", but there are a lot more.

You also might want a domain name (like www.mydomain.com). some hosting servies provide that as well.

I suggest you call them and ask them if they provide support for what you need.

Calling a remote service should be the same, all you have to do is change the url host, so instead of:

```
http://localhost
```

You'll put your domain:

```
http://mydomain.com
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured the answer would be something like this, just needed to be on the sure side. So much definitions on all of these hosting sites.